# Image Styling Effect

Tags: html, css, mobile

I have a client that wants the same image style effect as [WooTheme's Duo Theme](http://demo2.woothemes.com/?name=duo).  I can easily achieve this initial effect:

```
------HTML-------------
<div class="home-banner">

</div>

-------CSS-------------
.home-banner {
height: 500px;
background-image: url("CLIENT'S BG IMG");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
background-position: center;
padding: 9.505em 1.618em 11.089em;
text-align: center;
box-sizing: border-box;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
}

.home-banner:after {
content: "";
display: block;
height: 10em;
width: 200%;
position: absolute;
bottom: -5em;
right: -20em;
background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% #46535D;
border-radius: 100%;
transform: rotate(2deg);
border-top: 0.327em solid #F97960;
}
```

But there is one requirement that is killing the whole thing.  The client's photo is showing staff members of their company.  When the browser window is resized to simulate a tablet/smartphone, most of the image cannot be seen due to the css rule:

```
background-size: cover;
```

If I change this rule, the banner effect no longer works properly.  I need all staff members to be seen on a small display.  Imagine a staff member's head being cut off on their mobile device.  That means that my head would be next.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Use media queries to change the background-size depending on what you need and when you need it.

Comment: Use twitter bootstrap. It makes all these things really easy. Seems like a trite thing to say, but they make working with different devices a doddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a CSS media query such as

```
@media (max-width: 480px){  
/*Place mobile CSS here*/
}
```

This way whenever a user looks at this on a mobile device this CSS rule will override the normal browser one... just place it after the normal browser styling.

Comment: I've marked this as my answer.  Even though I'm just overlaying the image with a png at the bottom.  That solved my issue.  Thanks for your help just the same